# I want to parallel program in python with my pygame function and internet use

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pygame, multiprocessing, urllib

I am making a game and I am connecting it to internet. I use the following code to check internet connection:

```
def is_connected():
  try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname("www.google.co.in")
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
    pass
  return False
```

When I execute this code in my program so the cycle which has to run 60 times in a second(as I am ticking my fpsclock with 60) slow down my fps to 5 fps. I think
because its lagging too much.
I know that this is because this program is executed in the game loop and it has to run every time I update my screen
but please can anybody provide me a alternative to it.

I have heard the term parallel programming and it can be done in python but I am not sure how to do it or what type of parallel and where to implement it in my code.

Comment: This is way too broad for stack overflow. Google "Parallel Programming in Python" and you'll see a boatload of resources.

Comment: Do you really need to check tthe connectivity at each time you update the screen? I would could check the connectivity once at the beginning of the program, and later just handle network errors if any errors occur.

Comment: @Pedru nice idea i would try to figure to run it once

Comment: @skrrgwasme i tried googling it but the field is so broad that search results were far beyound my skills(like pool handling ), i cant implement that in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shard off the checking for connection into a less-repetitive time-interval or perhaps put it into its own thread or task. Or better yet, don't do it.**

Traditionally, calls to networking and sockets are managed by the operating system. This means that the operating system will need to manage its own stuff and try to connect to a host and then create a connection per frame here, by the code presented here.

Note that `connect()` (which is probably what the Python uses underneath; BSD sockets and the sort) is going to do its own networking stuff. As we all know, the quickness of Internet communication has a physical limit. Your computer is miles faster than a slow or mediocre connection.

**In my opinion, the best thing to do would be to send either a datagram or keep the connection established.** In C, a TCP/IP connection under BSD sockets with the C function `recv()` will normally return 0 only if the connection is closed. Normally, a connection will stay open under TCP/IP unless an error occurs or the connection closes.

**There is no reason you should be creating a new socket every frame.** A TCP/IP connection stream is meant to stay open once it is created. A UDP datagram is simply a packet of data, like a bullet firing from a gun. The idea that you need to keep establishing a connection is flawed from the start because connections are not streams, but streams of packets being managed (usually) by a protocol to make it seem that it works like a stream.

**If you really need to keep creating a socket each frame, do it outside of a main thread.** I'm sure Python has multithreading libraries. I'd suggest you don't go down this path because shared memory can be quite complicated. Networking and shared memory together will prove to be a headache.

Comment: yeah that would be a nice idea to maintain a stream of data like that happens in c++
but can you please tell me what python function can be used to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need multiprocessing in this case. you don't even need to check the connection that often. once every 5 seconds is enough, an probably won't make a noticable difference.